# Персонаж просто так умирает

Tags: unity3d, события

Есть персонаж, который при прикосновении к врагу теряет хп, есть код

```
  public class PlayerHealthbar : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Image progressImage;
    private int currentHP;
    private int maxHP;
    private float percentHP;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        
        EventBus.Instance.PlayerInit += SetStartHP;
        EventBus.Instance.PlayerHealed += OnPlayerHealed;
        EventBus.Instance.PlayerDamaged += OnTookDamage;
    }
    
    private void OnDisable() 
    {
        EventBus.Instance.PlayerHealed -= OnPlayerHealed;
    }

    private void Awake() 
    {
        progressImage = GetComponent<Image>();
    }

    private void SetStartHP(int hp)
    {
        Debug.Log($"player has {hp}");
        maxHP = hp;
        currentHP = maxHP;
        Debug.Log($"cur hp is {currentHP}");
    }
    
    private void OnTookDamage(int damage)
    {
        if(currentHP <= 0) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else {
            currentHP -= damage;
            progressImage.fillAmount -= (float)damage / currentHP;
            Debug.Log($"cur hp is {currentHP}");
        }
    }

    private void OnPlayerHealed(int amountOfRecover)
    {
        currentHP += amountOfRecover;
        progressImage.fillAmount += (float)amountOfRecover / currentHP;
        Debug.Log($"Player recovered {amountOfRecover}");
        Debug.Log($"cur hp is {currentHP}");
    }
```

Проблема заключается в том что персонаж умирает моментально при прикосновении к врагу, при этом дебаги отображают правильно хп, мол оно есть, но перс умер, не могу понять в чем проблема. Вот метод нанесения дамага врагом

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        EventBus.Instance.PlayerDamaged?.Invoke(damage);
    }
}
```

Вот состояние риджит бади объектов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот логи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может damage слишком большой получается?)) или по какой-то причине у вас метод ещё где-то срабаывает (например ещё где-нибудь какая-нибудь подписка стоит... или в методе Update повторный вызов есть и т.д.) .................. А вообще красным цветом вам ещё пишут о том, что вы не проверяете, что объекта нет на сцене и пытаетесь у него вызывать событие/метод.

Comment: А не может быть, что персонаж прикасается и каждый тик теряет здоровье? И за секунду метод срабатывает тысячу раз, например. Проверить можно выставив огромное здоровье и минимальный урон и посмотреть сколько времени уйдёт.

Comment: @Alexandr проблема именно в смерти при первом тике, метод срабатывает один раз при соприкосновении персонажа и врага, на логах видно, у меня 100 хп, враг наности 1 и персонаж умирает

Comment: У Вас нет никакой смерти (ни обособленного метода, ни события, ни логирования). У Вас просто уничтожение объекта, когда HP не положительное число. Либо объект удаляется в OnTookDamage() потому что HP <= 0 (н-р, в теории может быть потому, что OnTookDamage() вызывается раньше SetStartHP() и поэтому HP = 0). Либо удаление происходит в другом месте. Для начала определите, откуда именно вызывается удаление вашего объекта.